# Adding radio and check box totals?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, radio-button

I'm designing a online car shop as part of a small exercise. Everything going smoothly except for the total price. I want the selections to add on to the running total, depending on what radio button and check box I select, rather than each time a selection is made, the value of that selection accumulating on to my total. I hope I made explained that properly, I'd appreciate any help anyone can give!

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Configure Your GT  Sports Car</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="page-header">
    <header>
    <h1>Configure your GT Super Sportscar</h1>
    </header>
    </div></div></div>
    <form name="SportsCar" id="SportsCar">
    <p>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Configuration</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="format" id = "Manual" value="27790.00">
        <label for = "Manual">GT Manual - €27,790.00</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="format" id = "Automatic" value="28590.00">
        <label for = "Automatic">GT Automatic - €28,590.00</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="format" id = "Smanual" value="32455.00">
        <label for = "Smanual">GT-S Manual - €32,455.00</label>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="format" id = "Sautomatic" value="33155.00">
        <label for = "Sautomatic">GT-S Automatic - €33,155.00</label>
        <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>Car Colours</h3>
        <label for = "colour" >Please select a colour</label>
        <select name="colour" id="colour">
            <option value="black">Black</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="silver">Silver</option>
            <option value="white">White</option>
        </select>
        <img id="carImage" img src="images/black.jpg" alt="target_blank">
    </div></div></div></div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h3>Factory Options</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="fOptions" id="combo1" value="1235.00">
        <label for="combo1">Option Combo 1 - €1,235.00</label>
    <br>
    (Power windows, Doors, Cruise Control)
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fOptions" id="combo2" value="3354.00">
        <label for="combo2">Option Combo 2 - €3,354.00</label>
    <br>
    (Rear spoiler & Fog Lamps, Key-less Entry, Power Tilt & Slide Moonroof, Power windows, Doors, Cruise Control)
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fOptions" id="noExtras" value="0.00">
        <label for="noExtras">No Extras - €0</label>
    </div></div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">


    <h3>Dealer Options</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dealer" id="autochanger" value="550.00">
        <label for = "auto-changer">CD Auto-Changer - €550.00</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dealer" id="security" value="399.00">
        <label for = "security">VIP Security System - €399.00</label>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="dealer" id="mirror" value="295.00">
        <label for = "mirror">Auto Dimming Mirror - €295.00</label>
    <br>
    </div></div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <br>
     <label for="total" class="control-label col-md-2">Total Cost</label>
     <input type="text" name="total" id="total" maxlength="3" readonly>
     </div></div>
     </p>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var source = new Array();
    window.addEventListener("load", preLoad, false);

    function preLoad(){
        source[0]="images/black.jpg";
        source[1]="images/blue.jpg";
        source[2]="images/red.jpg";
        source[3]="images/silver.jpg";
        source[4]="images/white.jpg";
    }

    carColour = document.getElementById("colour");
    function handleColour(){
    if(carColour.selectedIndex==0)
    {
        theImage.src=source[0];
    }
    else if(carColour.selectedIndex==1)
    {
        theImage.src=source[1];
    }
    else if(carColour.selectedIndex==2)
    {
        theImage.src=source[2];
    }
    else if(carColour.selectedIndex==3)
    {
        theImage.src=source[3];
    }
    else if(carColour.selectedIndex==4)
    {
        theImage.src=source[4];
    }
    }
    theImage=document.getElementById("carImage");
    carColour.addEventListener("click", handleColour, false);


    </script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calculate.js"></script>
    </html>
```

Javascript

```
function formatCurrency(num) {
  num = num.toString().replace(/\€|\,/g,'');
  if(isNaN(num))
   {num = "0";}
  sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
  num = num.toFixed(2);
  elements= num.split(".");
  num = elements[0];
  cents = elements[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length-(1+i))/3); i++)
  {num = num.substring(0,num.length-(4*i+3))+','+
   num.substring(num.length-(4*0+3));}
  return (((sign)?'':'-') + '€' + num + '.' + cents)
}

window.addEventListener("load", handleLoad, false);
function handleLoad(){
runningTotal=parseInt(document.getElementById("Manual").value);
document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);
}

cars = document.getElementById("Manual");
cars.addEventListener("click", handleConfig, false);
function handleConfig(){
if(manual.checked){
    runningTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("manual").value);
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);

    }
}

cars = document.getElementById("Automatic");
cars.addEventListener("click", handleConfigOne, false);
function handleConfigOne(){
if(Automatic.checked){
    runningTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("Automatic").value);
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);

    }
}


cars = document.getElementById("Smanual");
cars.addEventListener("click", handleConfigTwo, false);
function handleConfigTwo(){
if(Smanual.checked){
    runningTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("Smanual").value);
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);

    }
}

cars = document.getElementById("Sautomatic");
cars.addEventListener("click", handleConfigThree, false);
function handleConfigThree(){
if(Sautomatic.checked){
    runningTotal = parseInt(document.getElementById("Sautomatic").value);
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);

    }
}





var option = document.getElementById("combo1");
option.addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);

function handleClick(){

    if(combo1.checked)
    {
    list=parseInt(document.getElementById("combo1").value);
    runningTotal+=list;
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);
    }
}

var factory = document.getElementById("combo2");
factory.addEventListener("click", handleExtrasTwo, false);

function handleExtrasTwo(){

    if(combo2.checked)
    {
    list=parseInt(document.getElementById("combo2").value);
    runningTotal+=list;
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);
    }
}

var extras = document.getElementById("noExtras");
extras.addEventListener("click", handleNoExtras, false);

function handleNoExtras(){
    if(noExtras.checked)
    {
    var noList=parseInt(document.getElementById("noExtras").value);
    runningTotal += noList;
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);
    }
}

var dealerOptions = document.getElementById("autochanger");
dealerOptions.addEventListener("click", handleOptions,false);

function handleOptions(){
    if(autochanger.checked)
    {
    autoChange=parseInt(document.getElementById("autochanger").value);
    runningTotal +=autoChange;
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);
    }
}

var dealerOption = document.getElementById("security");
dealerOption.addEventListener("click", handleOptionsTwo,false);

function handleOptionsTwo(){
    if(security.checked)
    {
    secure=parseInt(document.getElementById("security").value);
    runningTotal+=secure;
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);
    }
}


var dealerOptionThree = document.getElementById("mirror");
dealerOptionThree.addEventListener("click", handleOptionThree,false);

function handleOptionThree(){
    if(mirror.checked)
    {
    mirror=parseInt(document.getElementById("mirror").value);
    runningTotal += mirror;
    document.getElementById("total").value=formatCurrency(runningTotal);
}
}
```

Comment: Let me get this straight... You don't want the total to be increased on each click, but to show the total selected values on that instant, is that it?

Comment: At the moment each time I click a selection it adds that value to the total, but when I select another checkbox or radio button it does not delete the value added from the last selection, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

As you already have jquery included in your page, you should use it. It makes your life so much simpler. Using your code as a base, I've created a simple method to sum the values of the selected elements (radio or checkbox), and display it on the total textbox.
Then you will not have to put all those click events.
Check it out: (see the running example on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b3p4r/)

```
$("input").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("input").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("#total").val(formatCurrency(total));
});
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned in the OP we have not done JQuery yet, the piece of code you see was provided before we began the exercise, what Im looking to do wasnt essential for the exercise but I'd like to know how to do it anyway